# Tesnorflow model.fit shape incompatibility

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

Getting Error: "ValueError: Shapes (None, 5) and (None, 15, 5) are incompatible" while I am trying to train my model.

I am unable to figure where I am doing the error any help would be higly appreciated.

Total Output Category: 5

```
### Split the dataset into independent and dependent dataset
X = np.array(extracted_features_df['feature'].tolist())
y = np.array(extracted_features_df['class'].tolist())

### Train Test Split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
```

```
X_train.shape
X_test.shape
y_train.shape
y_test.shape
```

```
Output:
(200, 40)
(50, 40)
(200, 5)
(50, 5)
```

```
### Keras Model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=500, kernel_size=5, strides=1, activation='relu', input_shape=(40, 1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.999))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=500, kernel_size=7, strides=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.999))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=500, kernel_size=1, strides=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.999))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=3000, kernel_size=1, strides=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.999))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1500, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.999))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(600, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.999))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()
```

```
Output:
Model: "sequential_28"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv1d_70 (Conv1D)          (None, 36, 500)           3000      
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_72 (Bat  (None, 36, 500)          2000      
 chNormalization)                                                
                                                                 
 conv1d_71 (Conv1D)          (None, 15, 500)           1750500   
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_73 (Bat  (None, 15, 500)          2000      
 chNormalization)                                                
                                                                 
 conv1d_72 (Conv1D)          (None, 15, 500)           250500    
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_74 (Bat  (None, 15, 500)          2000      
 chNormalization)                                                
                                                                 
 conv1d_73 (Conv1D)          (None, 15, 3000)          1503000   
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_75 (Bat  (None, 15, 3000)         12000     
 chNormalization)                                                
                                                                 
 dense_40 (Dense)            (None, 15, 1500)          4501500   
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_76 (Bat  (None, 15, 1500)         6000      
 chNormalization)                                                
                                                                 
 dense_41 (Dense)            (None, 15, 600)           900600    
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_77 (Bat  (None, 15, 600)          2400      
 chNormalization)                                                
                                                                 
 dense_42 (Dense)            (None, 15, 5)             3005      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 8,938,505
Trainable params: 8,925,305
Non-trainable params: 13,200
_________________________________________________________________
```

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.05), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

```
Output:
ValueError: in user code:
...
    File "c:\Users\totha\anaconda3\envs\project_nn\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5532, in categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 5) and (None, 15, 5) are incompatible
```

I tried different input shape [like (None, 40), (40, )]on the 1st Cond1d layer but it didn't work.
Also changed the loss function to 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' but it throws a different error which is

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 5 and 15 for '{{node Equal}} = Equal[T=DT_FLOAT, incompatible_shape_error=true](IteratorGetNext:1, Cast_79)' with input shapes: [?,5], [?,15].
```

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow layer `Conv1D` accepts input as

```
3+D tensor with shape: batch_shape + (steps, input_dim)
```

and returns output as

```
3+D tensor with shape: batch_shape + (new_steps, filters)
```

which does not match with the given dataset output shape as mentioned in the model summary. Hence showing the above error.

Please use the `GlobalMaxPool1D()` layer to downsamples the input representation by taking the maximum value over the time dimension.

This will change the `Conv1D` output dim from (None, 15, 5) to (None, 5) and will not show any error.

Please find the replicated code [gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/42f00d5efebaa9de0e5b1ac8586dc5d3/75607723.ipynb) here for your reference.